# Admob error "Content URL must be non-empty." after start in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

can someone help me. I added Google Admob to my Flutter project and did everything according to the instructions. Now I get the following error message with the emulator.I haven't found anything in other forums. [image]

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(error, Content URL must be non-empty., null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Content URL must be non-empty.
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:4)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder.setContentUrl(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.1.0:2)
at io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.FlutterAdRequest.asAdRequest(FlutterAdRequest.java:68)
at io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.FlutterInterstitialAd.load(FlutterInterstitialAd.java:53)
at io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.onMethodCall(GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.java:304)
at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: Please add your error as text rather than a screenshot.  It's easier to look at depending on people's color schemes etc., more accessible, and also searchable for others who may have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the Problem with the follow things:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
```

and

```
compileSdkVersion 30


minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 30
```